# Why decrease new users show green positive google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, metrics

When i compare 2 time period, if there is decrease - does the % have to be red and negative no?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cnYV.png)

Answer (score 0):

1.389 users in the selected time interval compared to 1.260 users of the previous period.

An increase of 10.24% compared to the previous period. There is nothing strange.